# What is the Best C# Sortable Serialized List that can be used with DataContract?

Tags: c#, sortedlist, sortedset, immutable-collections

As a part of a class, I have some Immutable POCO objects just to act as a Data Transfer Object for a configuration file.

```
[DataMember]
public IReadOnlyList<Message> Messages { get; } = new List<Message>()
{
    new Warning(75, "UserMessage1", "LogMessage1"),
    new Warning(90, "UserMessage2", "LogMessage2"),
    new Error(100, "UserMessage3", "LogMessage3")
};
```

Message

```
abstract class Message
{
    protected Message(LogLevel logLevel, int percentUsed, string userMessage, string logMessage)
    {
        this.LogLevel = logLevel;
        this.PercentUsed = percentUsed;
        this.UserMessage = userMessage;
        this.LogMessage = logMessage;
    }

    LogLevel LogLevel { get; }

    [DataMember]
    int PercentUsed { get; }
    [DataMember]
    string UserMessage { get; }
    [DataMember]
    string LogMessage { get; }
}

[DataContract]
internal sealed class Warning : Message
{
    public Warning(int percentUsed, string userMessage, string logMessage) : base(LogLevel.Warn, percentUsed, userMessage, logMessage)
    {
    }
}

[DataContract]
internal sealed class Error : Message
{
    public Error(int percentUsed, string userMessage, string logMessage) : base(LogLevel.Error, percentUsed, userMessage, logMessage)
    {
    }
}
```

And I'm hoping to be able to serialize it out to the following XML (or potentially JSON in the future?)

```
<Messages>
  <Warning>
    <PercentageUsed>75</PercentageUsed>
    <UserMessage>UserMessage1</UserMessage>
    <LogMessage>LogMessage1</LogMessage>
  </Warning>
  <Warning>
    <PercentageUsed>90</PercentageUsed>
    <UserMessage>UserMessage2</UserMessage>
    <LogMessage>LogMessage2</LogMessage>
  </Warning>
  <Error>
    <PercentageUsed>100</PercentageUsed>
    <UserMessage>UserMessage3</UserMessage>
    <LogMessage>LogMessage3</LogMessage>
  </Error>
</Messages>
```

Later I'll be using this configuration in order to make a sorted list, so that I can grab the appropriate warning and log level for the amount of disk space used. e.g. I have 77% disk space used, grab me the appropriate error message (75%) from the sorted list.

Can I make List use SortedList and still maintain the XML output I'm looking for using DataContract's?

Can I keep my class Immutable?

Or am I just better off using a List for simplicity and LINQ for the ease of use?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your current output? From the question now, it doesn't look like there's any problem, I just looks like you don't want to try it :)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit This question is not related to concrete code like 'why this is not working', but instead 'should I go way A or B and why?'. I feel this is exactly the question where some experienced developer should provide advanced answer "in bigger picture".

Comment: @Tatranskymedved If you have any suggestions as to how I can reword my question to make it clear that is my intent and more useful to SO, I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: I ended up just using a list and giving up on having it sorted.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I got an idea about moving this question to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ where it might receive appropriate attention?

Comment: I'm well past looking for a answer just ended up hacking something together. Is there a way to just move it cross site? Whatever improves the communities